# creating CAML queries in a 32 bit environment?

Tags: caml, query

I'm currently developing with SharePoint on my 32 bit computer. While I'm able to make simple changes with designer on my PC I'm aware that using visual studio to make changes (CAML queries) without the server installed is not possible within my desktop.

Is there any way of being able to create these CAML queries without having to install SharePoint server? Upgrading to 64bit is not an option for me at the moment

Comment: you can use SPCAMLQueryHelper to create CAML queries using SharePoint Web services. http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: what are the web services?

Comment: Web services basically let you work remotely with SP services, so you don't have to have SP installed on your local machine to interact with it. The instructions with the program @FalakMahmood mentioned should tell you how to set it up. Falak, you should post that as an answer so the OP has the option of accepting it.

Comment: Thanks! Will this let me create joins between different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify whether or not you're developing against SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013. If it's SharePoint 2010, **CAMLDesigner** for SP2010 will run in a 32-bit environment and will allow you to connect using either the SharePoint Web Services or the Client Side Object Model.

The appropriate version can be **downloaded here**:
http://www.camldesigner.com/

(I haven't tried CAMLDesigner for SP2013 in a 32-bit environment -- but be aware it needs .Net 4.5)

Comment: Thanks for this, I've only just downloaded it. Do you know if it's possible to create different joins with the CAMLDesigner?

Comment: According to comment #10 on [Karine Bosch's blog](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/caml-designer-for-sharepoint-2013/), as of August 11 2013, CAML Designer doesn't support JOINs.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestions how I could perform joins in my environment?

Comment: You want to execute CAML queries containing JOINs? You can use the Client-Side Object Model. The CSOM lets you, among many other things, execute CAML queries against any SharePoint server, running on your local machine or not, and manipulate the output.

Here's an example to get you started.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-Introduction

Here's a primer on manually building your own CAML query using projected lists/fields:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: I keep following tutorials that require the ISAPI folder within     %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\.    

However my \14\ folder only contains the BIN folder. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Developing with the CSOM only requires the Client assemblies; you don't need any other SharePoint-related settings on your DEV machine. I'm starting to get the feeling you don't have an actual SharePoint server you can "call" using the CSOM. Am I missing something?